# find the nearest point pairs between two sets of of matrix

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor

Assume I have two sets of matrix (**A** and **B**), inside each matrix contains few point coordinates, I want to find out point in **B** nearest to **A** and output a cell array **C** listed the nearest point pair coordinates accordingly and one cell array **D** register the unpaired spot, how should I do it?

To be more specific, here is what I want

Two sets of matrix contain spot xy coordinates;

```
A=[ 1 2; 3 4]; B=[1 3; 5 6; 2 1];
```

want to get `C{1,1}=[1 2; 1 3]; C{2,1}= [3 4; 5 6]; D{1,1}=[2 1];`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can elements from A and/or B be reused? What sort of distance do you want to minimize?

Comment: @ aschepler, the elements from A and B can not be reused. I do not quite understand your second question, but what I want is the minimum point to point distance. Hope this clarify my question.

Comment: @ aschepler, I guess I understand your second question now, I modify my question a bit, hope this clarify the second point you made.

Comment: Have you looked into using `dsearchn`?

Comment: @ Ansari, I guess dsearchn may not be useful here because the elements from A and B can not be reused.

Comment: Have a look at my response to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639925/how-to-find-the-closest-vector-to-a-given-vector-in-matlab/10648151#10648151 Although I was finding a mean closest difference, on the way to finding that it will have to compute what you are looking for.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631934/sort-coordinates-points-in-matlab/11632176#11632176

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not exactly one solution to this problem, take for example the (one-dimensional, but expandable to N-D) case:

```
A= [1; 3];
B= [2];
```

Then either `A(1)` or `A(2)` can be the leftover point. Which one your algorithm spits out, will depend on how it works, ie which point you take first to find the nearest point.

Such algorithm consists imo of

1. Finding distances between each combination of `A(i)` and `B(j)`. If you have the statistics toolbox, [pdist2](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/stats/pdist2.html) does this for you:

   ```
   A=[ 1 2; 3 4];
   B=[1 3; 5 6; 2 1];
   dist = pdist2(A,B);
   ```
2. Looping over the smallest of `A` or `B` (I'll take A, cause it is smallest in your example) and finding for each point in `A` the closest point in the remaining set of `B`:

   ```
   N = size(A,1);
   matchAtoB=NaN(N,1);
   for ii=1:N
       dist(:,matchAtoB(1:ii-1))=Inf; % make sure that already picked points of B are not eligible to be new closest point
       [~,matchAtoB(ii)]=min(dist(ii,:));
   end
   matchBtoA = NaN(size(B,1),1);
   matchBtoA(matchAtoB)=1:N;
   remaining_indices = find(isnan(matchBtoA));
   ```
3. Combine result to your desired output matrices `C` and `D`:

   ```
   C=arrayfun(@(ii) [A(ii,:) ; B(matchAtoB(ii),:)],1:N,'uni',false);
   D=mat2cell(B(remaining_indices,:),ones(numel(remaining_indices),1),size(B,2));
   ```

Note that this code will also work with 1D points or higher (N-D), the `pdist2` flattens everything out to scalar distances.

Comment: @ Gunther, Just found a bug, if A=[1 2; 3 4], B=[1 3]; when I run the code, both [1 2] and [3 4] are group with [1 3], what should I do to get C{1,1}=[1 2;1 3] and C{1,2}=[3 4]? thanks

Comment: It's not a bug, read my code: '2. Looping over the smallest of `A` or `B`'; So if `B` is smaller, switch `A` and `B`!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on the problem:

```
A=[1 2
   3 4]; 

B=[1 3
   5 6
   2 1];

dists = pdist2(A,B);

[dists, I] = sort(dists,2);

c = NaN(size(A,1),1);
for ii = 1:size(A,1)    
    newC = find(~any(bsxfun(@eq, I(ii,:), c), 1));
    c(ii) = I(ii,newC(1));
end

C = cellfun(@(x)reshape(x,2,2).',...
        mat2cell([A B(c,:)], ones(size(A,1),1), 4), 'uni', false);
D = {B(setdiff(1:size(B,1),c), :)}
```

This solution assumes

- all your vectors are 2D
- stacked in rows of `A` and `B`
- and `A` is always the source (i.e., everything is compared to `A`)

If these assumptions do not (always) hold, you'll have to take a more general approach, like the one suggested by @GuntherStruyf.

Comment: What about `A=[0 0;1 1]` and `B=[1 1;0 0;2 2]`? For this input, the result is `I= [2 ; 2]`! I don't see how setting lower triangular part of `dists` to `NaN` solves the problem of not using elements of `B` multiple times. You don't know in advance which points lies closest together, unless everything is already sorted, in which this question is useless...

Comment: @GuntherStruyf Yep, my solution was wrong; I was blinded by the correct outcomes for this particular problem. This edit should rectify that.

Comment: @GuntherStruyf I still don't like that for loop though...I feel there is a function for that, but it doesn't come to mind...

Comment: You _have_ to handle each coordinate in `A` one at a time, because it affects the solution of other coordinates in `A`. There is no straightforward/loop-free/non-iterative solution for this problem imo.

Comment: @GuntherStruyf is that downvote yours? Granted, yours is the more elegant (and faster!) solution, but a downvote...be a sport :)

Comment: downvoted because it was wrong in the first place, hadn't time yet to verify your correction, but it looks okay now though ;) I immediately saw the problem with your first solution, the correction looks a bit more complicated to go through quickly :p