# MATLAB short way to find closest vector?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, built-in, euclidean-distance

In my application, I need to find the "closest" (minimum Euclidean distance vector) to an input vector, among a set of vectors (i.e. a matrix)

Therefore every single time I have to do this :

```
function [match_col] = find_closest_column(input_vector, vectors)
cmin = 99999999999; % current minimum distance
match_col = -1;    

    for col=1:width
        candidate_vector = vectors(:,c); % structure of the input is not important
        dist = norm(input_vector - candidate_vector);
        if dist < cmin
            cmin = dist;
            match_col = col;
        end
    end
```

is there a built-in MATLAB function that does this kind of thing easily (with a short amount of code) for me ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find the closest vector to a given vector in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639925/how-to-find-the-closest-vector-to-a-given-vector-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist2.html). Assuming (from your code) that your vectors are columns, transposition is needed because `pdist2` works with rows:

```
[cmin, match_col] = min(pdist2(vectors.', input_vector.' ,'euclidean'));
```

It can also be  done with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/bsxfun.html) (in this case it's easier to work directly with columns):

```
[cmin, match_col] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, vectors, input_vector).^2));
cmin = sqrt(cmin); %// to save operations, apply sqrt only to the minimizer
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I actually don't need the cmin value. I only need `match_col`. and what is the `@minus` operator doing? If it was `@plus`, then would it return the far-est vector ?

Comment: The `@minus` is just the minus sign that you use in computing the Euclidean distance (within each square term). To find the farthest vector, change `min` to `max` (keeping `@minus`)

Comment: Ok, I don't have time to try now but I trust this is the correct answer. Thanks again !

Answer (score 3):

`norm` can't be directly applied to every column or row of a matrix, so you can use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
dist = arrayfun(@(col) norm(input_vector - candidate_vector(:,col)), 1:width);
[cmin, match_col] = min(dist);
```

This solution was also given [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/172116).

**HOWEVER**, this solution is [much much slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why) than doing a direct computation using `bsxfun` (as in Luis Mendo's answer), so it should be avoided. `arrayfun` should be used for more complex functions, where a vectorized approach is harder to get at.

Comment: +1 But take into account that [`arrayfun` may not be the fastest approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why)

Comment: Yes exactly what I wrote you. So should I delete this?

Comment: It's not the fastest approach, but I don't think it should be necessarily deleted.

Comment: I edited it with a warning and your link, so it's clear this should not be the solution of choice.